# Correct way of working with SVG in a TypeScript React project with ESlint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack, eslint

In my project I am using such technologies as TypeScript, React and ESlint. 
The problem is that eslint is always rising an error for svg files
"Unsafe assignment of an any value.(eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment)". 
[image]

In root of my src folder I have custom.d.ts with svg module declared:

```
// declare module "*.svg";

declare module "*.svg" {
  import * as React from "react";

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }
  >;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

tried both declarations commented one and the one taken from create-react-app.
The way I am using SVG's in the project:

```
import Logo from "images/logo.svg";

<Link to={PATH.ROOT} className={styles.logo}>
    <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" className={styles.icon} />
     <span className={styles.title}>Ascension Wiki</span>
</Link>
```

To get rid of the error I can use type casting like:

```
<img src={Logo as string} alt="Logo" className={styles.icon} />
```

Or turn off the rule in ESlint, but I think there should be a better way of dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using this declaration removes the eslint error for me:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Comment: i'd give your a reward for this if i could. best answer to this problem on the internet. remember to add `custom.d.ts` in the `include` section of `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did work for me, maybe I did something wrong, but I just added `as string`, for example `<Image src={RightArrow as string} />` and that did the trick.